# Gemini and SpiraTest Interaction

Tags: testing, integration, release, gemini

Is there functionality or an Add-on available that allows Gemini and SpiraTest to communicate with one another?  For example, I have software development and releases managed through Gemini, but my testing handled through SpiraTest and I would like to hook the two systems up to one another, is this possible with an out-the-box solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no integration out of the box. However...

1. You could [build an app](http://docs.countersoft.com/developing-ui-apps/) in Gemini that linked to SpiraTest
2. You can just use the [test management capability](http://docs.countersoft.com/sentry-testing/) in Gemini

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for responding, much appreciated